# RadTextBox TextChanged event only fired once

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-ajax

I am using OnTextChanged event of a TextBox run code behind if it lost focus , When the page is firstly load, it can trigger the behind code. However, after the first time running the behind code, if I go back to the textbox and make it lost focus again, it does not do any code behind again. How can I make the textbox trigger code behind each time it lost focus.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="uiToLocation" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true"
                    OnTextChanged="uiToLocation_Leave" EmptyMessage="<%$ Resources:ResourceHKEx,Arrive_To %>" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The back code, main aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;


namespace WebHKEx
{
    public partial class FlightEdit : Web.CustomPage
    {

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // initialize variables
            InitializeVariables();

            // permission checking
            VerifyUserPermissions(true);

            // initialize controls
            InitializeControls();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }        

    } // end class
} // end namespace
```

And the code behind is in a subcontrol cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace WebHKEx.WebControls
{
    public partial class UsageControl2SubControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(uiRemoved.Value))
            {
                this.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        protected void uiToLocation_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                uiDistance = "123";

        }
    }// end class
}// end namespace
```

Comment: Could you give your back code

Comment: In web form not exist implementation lose focus it can be make only js

Comment: the `OnTextChanged` is fired as its name suggest on every keystroke inside the textbox..

Comment: are you updating/changing content of the textbox again and then change the focus out from the textbox?

Comment: @KevinShah I updating/changing the content of the textbox again and then change the focus out from the textbox, it triggers the code behind again. Thanks

Comment: without any change in the textbox content event will not be trigger as View state value is not being updated so there is nothing to be post.

Comment: @KevinShah can I make it run the code behind just for change the focus out from the textBox?

Comment: You can do that using javascript. on focus out you have to call javascript function and on that function you need to write code to call textchange event or you can call button click event